# How to add "SP.FieldLookup field with REST?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Why I can't directly create a SP.FieldLookup with REST? Creating a SP.FieldCreationInformation works fine but hasn't all properties I need (e.g. Description or RelationshipDeleteBehavior).

Thx in advance!

**// SP.FieldCreationInformation is WORKING**

```
var data = { parameters: {
    __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.FieldCreationInformation' },
    FieldTypeKind: 7,
    Title: 'TestLookup',
    LookupListId: '809f8f9d-5b41-476f-9765-016bbb5ef36a',
    LookupFieldName: 'Title'
}};


$.ajax({
    url: "https://.../_api/lists(guid'd8392641-0422-4b06-97ec-621650c89c9c')/fields/addfield",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { 
        "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(d) { alert("added"); },
    error: function(e) { alert("error"); }
});
```

**// SP.FieldLookup is NOT WORKING**

```
var data = {
    __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.FieldLookup' },
    FieldTypeKind: 7,
    Title: 'TestLookup',
    LookupList: '809f8f9d-5b41-476f-9765-016bbb5ef36a',
    LookupField: 'Title'
};

$.ajax({
    url: "https://.../_api/lists(guid'd8392641-0422-4b06-97ec-621650c89c9c')/fields",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { 
        "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(d) { alert("added"); },
    error: function(e) { alert("error"); }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, for setting other properties you need to edit call again.. Though I have not tried below but you can check..

**MERGE** request example: Change a lookup field

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists(guid'da58632f-faf0-4a78-8219-99c307747741')
    /fields('1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1')",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldLookup' }, 'AllowMultipleValues': true ,'RelationshipDeleteBehavior' : 1}",
  headers: { 
    "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value>,
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-length": <length of body data>,
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Gets or sets a value that specifies the delete behavior of the lookup field. Represents a RelationshipDeleteBehaviorType value: None = 0, Cascade = 1, Restrict = 2. See RelationshipDeleteBehavior in the .NET client object model reference for more information about this property.

Reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/office/dn600182.aspx#bk_FieldLookup)-